# How can I generate a list of #define values from C code?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have code that has a lot of complicated #define error codes that are not easy to decode since they are nested through several levels.

Is there any elegant way I can get a list of #defines with their final numerical values (or whatever else they may be)?

As an example:

```
<header1.h>
#define CREATE_ERROR_CODE(class, sc, code) ((class << 16) & (sc << 8) & code)
#define EMI_MAX 16

<header2.h>
#define MI_1 EMI_MAX

<header3.h>
#define MODULE_ERROR_CLASS MI_1
#define MODULE_ERROR_SUBCLASS 1
#define ERROR_FOO CREATE_ERROR_CODE(MODULE_ERROR_CLASS, MODULE_ERROR_SUBCLASS, 1)
```

I would have a large number of similar #defines matching ERROR_[\w_]+ that I'd like to enumerate so that I always have a current list of error codes that the program can output. I need the numerical value because that's all the program will print out (and no, it's not an option to print out a string instead).

Suggestions for gcc or any other compiler would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered **using real constants** instead of #defines?

Comment: Changing the code to consts would not be practical since it is inherited from an upstream source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution is a combo of @nmichaels and @aschepler's answers.

Use gcc's -dM option to get a list of the macros. 
 Use perl or awk or whatever to create 2 files from this list:

1) Macros.h, containing just the #defines.

2) Codes.c, which contains

```
#include "Macros.h"

ERROR_FOO = "ERROR_FOO"
ERROR_BAR = "ERROR_BAR"
```

(i.e: extract each `#define  ERROR_x` into a line with the macro and a string.

now run `gcc -E Codes.c`.   That should create a file with all the macros expanded.  The output should look something like

```
1 = "ERROR_FOO"
2 = "ERROR_BAR"
```

*I don't have gcc handy, so haven't tested this...*

Comment: I tried this and with a mere 6 perl one liners of processing I finally ended up with a sorted list of numeric values! One problem with this solution is gcc -E -P gives me a massive file with all the preprocessed headers. I removed -P and took only the lines after "# 2 Codes.c 2". Fix this and I think you win the bounty...

Comment: done.  -P was supposed to "Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor", which seemed useful for making the file look cleaner.  Oh well.

Comment: The key concept I missed here was that I could not just preprocess the header, I needed to run a C file referencing those constants to actually expand it. The other part I missed I figured out myself: I can only get as far as an arithmetic expression, which I need to eval. Technically I suppose I need to compile it, but I cheated and passed it to perl eval.

Answer (score 7):

GCC's `-dM` [preprocessor option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) might get you what you want.

Comment: This seems like the right idea, but it doesn't expand my macros. I've tried running `gcc -E -Wp,-dD header3.h and I end up with the exact same #define as defined above.

Comment: @djs: Yeah, it's not quite all the way. `-dM` will output a list of macros that you can feed into a script to generate the expansions though.

Comment: The end result though is I have a list of function-like macros that the preprocessor can expand, but which I certainly don't want to do. So I need some way to expand them...

Answer (score 2):

The program ['coan'](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/coan_man_1.html) looks like the tool you are after.  It has the 'defs' sub-command, which is described as:

> defs [OPTION...] [file...] [directory...]
>
> Select `#define` and `#undef` directives from the input files in accordance with the options and report them on the standard output in accordance with the options.

See the cited URL for more information about the options.  Obtain the code [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/coan2/files/).

Comment: Interesting application. I was really excited about it until I discovered that it doesn't support expansion of function-like macros. There's a defect open to fix this though, so perhaps someday it will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a complete list of the macros you want to see, and all are numeric, you can compile and run a short program just for this purpose:

```
#include <header3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHOW(x) printf(#x " = %lld\n", (long long int) x)

int main(void) {
    SHOW(ERROR_FOO);
    /*...*/
    return 0;
}
```

As @nmichaels mentioned, gcc's `-d` flags may help get that list of macros to show.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little creative solution:

Write a program to match all of your identifiers with a regular expression (like `\#define :b+(?<NAME>[0-9_A-Za-z]+):b+(?<VALUE>[^(].+)$` in .NET), then have it create another C file with just the names matched:

```
void main() {
    /*my_define_1*/ my_define_1;
    /*my_define_2*/ my_define_2;
    //...
}
```

Then pre-process your file using the /C /P option (for VC++), and you should get all of those replaced with the values. Then use another regex to swap things around, and put the comments before the values in `#define` format -- now you have the list of `#define`'s!

(You can do something similar with GCC.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any elegant way I can get a list of #defines with their final numerical values

For various levels of elegance, sort of.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="mount.c";
for macro in $(grep -Po '(?<=#define)\s+(\S+)' "$file"); do
    echo -en "$macro: ";
    echo -en '#include "'"$file"'"\n'"$macro\n" | \
    cpp -E -P -x c ${CPPFLAGS} - | tail -n1;
done;
```

Not foolproof (`#define \ \n macro(x) ...` would not be caught - but no style I've seen does *that*).