# How can I list all #define'd values before compilation?

Tags: visual-studio, gcc

I am interested in seeing all the values that are defined by the preprocessor before the compiler itself is invoked.

Is there a flag of some sort to stop the compiler (VS or gcc) before actual compiling and get it to print out all values that have been set with #define statements? I am not only interested in seeing the #define statements from my own program, but also from the standard libraries, such as GENERIC_READ, etc

So ideally a session would look like:

```
cl /someflag mycode.c
> #define GENERIC_READ 0x80000000
> #define GENERIC_WRITE 0x40000000
> ...
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597775/844207

Comment: That is very helpful for GCC thank you!Any pointers for Visual Studio?